# How can I get msys to recognize gcc?

Tags: gcc, msys

I am trying to install a library with msys. Unfortunately when I tried `.\configure` msys "could not find a working compiler". I have gcc installed as a part of MinGW. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: I have gcc as a PATH variable, so running `gcc.exe` from powershell works.

Comment: You need to look at config.log and find out what the actual error was.

Comment: @n.m. Where in the logfile is the error?

Comment: Probably somewhere near the word "error", search it in an editor. if it's not there, try "fail", or "could not find a working compiler".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue. I just had to restart msys after setting the PATH environment variable.